# Is it possible to fill a variable in the .gitlab-ci.yml file per python script?

Tags: python, variables, gitlab, yaml

I do not manage to declare global variables in the .gitlab-ci.yml file and assign a value to them via python script. 
I want to extract a value from a .ini file and assign it to the variable in yaml so that I have it available in all jobs.

no matter if with variables: in the yaml file still with pyyaml I manage it.

In the YAML FILE I tried the following to save the output of the Python script into the YAML variable. Once under variables ...:

```
    variables:
        appIdentifier: "" #=python3.7 ./gitLabCI/fill_appIdentifier.py
```

... and once under before_script:

```
    befor_script:
            - appIdentifier=$(python3.7 ./gitLabCI/fill_appIdentifier.py)
```

The following PYTHON script returns a value (string) that I want to assign to the YAML variable appIdentifier. In this case the ouput is web-hook:

```
    def fill_appIdentifier():
        appIdentifier = None
        repoName = globalVars.initialize_repo_name()
        print("repo name: {0}".format(repoName))
        module = get_value_from_releasnotes.getValueFromReleasnotes('module', False)
        print('module: {0}'.format(module))
        if(repoName == 'spar-egrocery'):
            appIdentifier = module
            print(appIdentifier)
            return appIdentifier
        else:
            appIdentifier = repoName
            print(appIdentifier)
            return appIdentifier

    fill_appIdentifier()
```

So the variable in the yaml file should then look like this: appIdentifier: web-hook

Comment: Your YAML is invalid. You cannot have a block style list item (`- autobuild....` and a dict key (`egrocery_tag: ..` within the same node. If you don't provide valid input it is guesswork on how to get something that works. What does the second file (after "or") represent. Please provide the input you have (YAML and INI) and the output you expect (updated YAML)

Comment: @Anthon: 
Thank you for your answer, I have now amended the question and I hope that I have resolved the confusion. THX

Answer (score 0):

the solution, at least for me, is the following:

```
before_script:
- export appIdentifier=$(python3.7 ./gitLabCI/fill_appIdentifier.py)
- export autobuild=$(python3.7 ./gitLabCI/get_value_from_releasnotes.py 'auto-build')
- export egrocery_tag=$(python3.7 ./gitLabCI/get_value_from_releasnotes.py 'egrocery_tag')
```

This allows me to access the variables in all subsequent stages.

THX